# Canoscan Lide 60 not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: canon, scanner, xsane

After Installing Ubuntu 13.10, my scanner not working, or not detected in xsane, please help me to connect my scanner.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Ubuntu 14.04) it worked out of the box, but I had to start an application called "Simple Scan". With this program it works perfectly!!

Comment: IIRC, Simple Scan links into XSane. If XSane doesn't work, Simple Scan shouldn't. I may be wrong, thouhg.